# Command Backspace keep going past the line

Tags: shortcut

I'm running OS X Yosemite. <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> deletes a whole line in every app. In some apps, it deletes a whole line and keeps deleting lines after that. In some, it deletes a whole line and stops, so I have to hit delete to move up to the previous line and then Command-Delete to delete a whole line again.

Is there a way to make it keep deleting lines in every app. The one I'm specifically talking about is Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I think <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> may be what you are looking for.

Edit: mistyped the shortcut :P

Comment: Option Delete is close, but it deletes just one word. It's quick and spans multi-line which is nice, but I'm specifically looking for Command Delete multiline.